# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using css styling with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I tried to set style to my page using css but i got this exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XRetailMobile.Views.MainPage" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XRetailMobile.Views.ContentViews"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <StyleSheet Source="/Styles/style.css"/>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">           
            <local:ProductBackToolbar StyleClass="toolbarStyle" VerticalOptions="Start">
            </local:ProductBackToolbar>

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

ProductBackToolbar.xaml(contentview)

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="back" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Image>
        <Image Source="share" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="35" HorizontalOptions="End"></Image>
        <Image Source="shoppingbag" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="35" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

style.css Located in Style Folder and its build action is EmbeddedResources

```
^contentpage {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
.toolbarStyle {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 20px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

if i comment margin and padding it's work fine
what's the wrong ?

Comment: Style Folder or Styles Folder? Because you said Style Folder, but in your code is Styles Folder.

Comment: Styles in code and folder name margin and padding doesn't work and if i comment it it's work

Comment: What mean this symbol **"^"** before `contentpage`?

Comment: Elements in the visual tree can be selected by base class with the case insensitive ^base
check the doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/

Comment: Then would be `div[class^=contentpage]`instead. This approach would take all `div` with class starting  `contentpage`, all right? Make this and try out. But this way i didn't know.